# how to define a different item or object that I draw with UIView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have more Items like Icon of iPhone that I draw in UIView. I want to increase the quantity of each item which I used the same method when I clicked. The problem is, when I click one Item (2 times) the quantity has increased. After I click on another item the quantity didn't count from 0 but it count the value that count from first Item. It mean that I click on the second Item 2 times so the quantity is 4 not 0. How we can define the different object but use the same method? Here is my code :

```
-(void)showOrderedQuantityLabel:(ItemView *)itv{
int counts =1;
counts =counts+clickOn;
float x = itv.frame.origin.x + 17;
float y = itv.frame.origin.y - 10;
UIImageView *anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 30, 30)];
anImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"productNote.png"];

UILabel *increaseQty =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 20)];
increaseQty.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
increaseQty.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
increaseQty.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
increaseQty.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
increaseQty.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counts];
clickOn++;
[anImageView addSubview:increaseQty];
[self.scrollView addSubview:anImageView];
[self performSelector:@selector(removeIndicatorView:) withObject:anImageView   afterDelay:0.4];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better that you use a NSMutableArray to keep track of the `count` of each item.